# Using tailwind css I'm trying to add a smooth top to down transition as the div is visible in conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make an accordian in react with tailwinf css. But I'm not able to apply a top to down  transition as the div becomes visible with conditional rendering.

```
const \[expanded, setExpanded\] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded)
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center my-3 px-4">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full border-b-2 border-rose-500">
                <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-black/90">
                    Title
                </h2>
                <div
                    className={`text-3xl opacity-90 transition duration-200 ${expanded ? 'rotate-90' : 'rotate-0'}`}
                    onClick={handleClick}
                >
                    <FaCaretRight />
                </div>
            </div>
            {expanded &&
                <div className="p-3 text-xl tansition duration-300">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam illo quo inventore ducimus qui animi corrupti nostrum, culpa est cum.
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </>
   )
}
```